# Show only content in page after action click in Wordpress admin

Tags: admin, actions, buttons

I have an custom post with actions and I like to show only the content with I clicked on this action button.

This is the action registered when I clicked on an custom button action:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'houzez_fill_listing');
function houzez_fill_listing() {

    global $post;

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['action'])) {

        if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'confirm_listing') {

            $post_id = absint($_GET['fill_building']);

            $listing_data = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_status' => 'occupied'
            );
            wp_update_post($listing_data);

            update_post_meta($post_id, 'fave_property_status_building', '2');
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'fave_property_availability_start', $_GET['start_date']);
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'fave_property_availability_end', $_GET['end_date']);

            $author_id  = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
            $user       = get_user_by('id', $author_id );
            $user_email = $user->user_email;

            $args = array(
                'listing_title' => get_the_title($post_id),
                'listing_url' => get_permalink($post_id)
            );
            houzez_email_type( $user_email,'listing_expired', $args );

            wp_redirect(remove_query_arg('fill_listing', add_query_arg('fill_listing', $post_id, admin_url('edit.php?post_type=property'))));

        }

    } else {

        if(!empty($_REQUEST['fill_listing'])) {

            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Confirmación para ocupar este inmueble</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="<?=admin_url( 'admin.php' )?>">
             <input type="hidden" name="action" value="confirm_listing" />
             <input type="hidden" name="building_id" value="'.$_REQUEST['fill_listing'].'" />
             <p>Nota: esta acción solo puede ser aplicada para ofertas que se encuentran con la condición de alquiler y alquiler temporario.</p>
             <p>Elija la fecha inicial y final para confirmar la ocupación del inmueble.</p>
             <div>';
              <p>Fecha inicio: <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" /></p>
              <p>Fecha fin: <input type="text" name="end_date" id="start_date" /></p>
             </div>';

            <?=submit_button('Confirmar acción').' '.submit_button('Cancelar','secondary','','','onClick="location.href=\''.wp_get_referer().'\'"');?>
            </form>
            </div>
            <?

            return false;

        } else {


        }

    }

}
```

After clicked I show like the image:

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rAw6.jpg

What I have to do for SHOW ONLY the content up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to create a page with your own content, you can do like that :

```
add_action("admin_menu", function () {

    $post_type = get_post_type_object("property");

    add_submenu_page(
          " "
        , "Page title"
        , ""
        , $post_type->cap->edit_posts
        , "property__validationForm"
        , function () {
            do_action("property/validationForm");
        }
    );

});


add_action("property/validationForm", function () {

    ?>

        <pre><?php var_dump($_GET);?></pre>

        form

    <?php

});
```

to create a URL to this page, use this code :

```
$url = admin_url("admin.php");

$url = add_query_arg([
    "page" => "property__validationForm",
    "property_ID" => $property->ID,
], $url);
```

for more informations about the function `add_submenu_page`, you can look in the codex :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Comment: Works perfect!!! Now I have a question. In the add_action "admin_menu" you declare the variable $post_type, this is neccesary? Thanks!

Comment: it was a mistake, I have corrected my answser